# Linear Algebra vectors proof?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have looked at this question and don't understand almost everything about it. Looking for a detailed answer. 
For any two vectors a and b,

Show that $|a+b|^2 + |a-b|^2 = 2|a|^2 +2|b|^2$

Comment: When you say "you don't understand almost everything about it", it would be helpful if you could be more specific.  Do you understand what the symbols mean? If so, what have you tried so far?  Also: you've copied the formula incorrectly

Comment: If you do not understand a question then why do you ask for an answeer? Ask what this question means? Asking for a detailed answer sounds like saying "Give me an  answer for free for my home work, I don't care what it means".

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** [The parallelogram identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Apollonius' Theorem

Also, if you are not getting a problem, it is better to ask for a hint rather than a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write out all the norms in terms of dot products, i.e., $|x|^2=x\cdot x$, and use the distributive law.